# CNN seemingly not even trying to learn

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a CNN, but it seems to output the same thing regardless of input, except between training steps, when its output is altered slightly with each training step. I've tried changing the size of the network, the learning rate, the loss function etc. etc. Regardless of what I do, my training graph is always some variation of this:

[image: Training graph]

The data in question is Stock market data, so it's possible it's either beyond the scope of my network or beyond the scope of CNNs in general. *However*, I am using the same structure as is used in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/348365232_A_CNN-based_Stock_Price_Trend_Prediction_with_Futures_and_Historical_Price), which achieves solid results, so I should be getting at least some improvement in accuracy.

I don't really know what I've done wrong, and any tips or directions are much appreciated.

Code for the Model:

```
class ClassifierModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(
    self,
    input_shape, 
    output_shape,
    path=None,
    class_frequencies=None,
    lr=1e-3,
):
    super(ClassifierModel, self).__init__()
    self.path = path

    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 4, 3, padding=1)
    self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, padding=1, stride=1)
    self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(4)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(4, 8, 3, padding=1)
    self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, padding=1, stride=1)
    self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(8)
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(8, 8, 3, padding=1)
    self.maxpool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, padding=1, stride=1)
    self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(8)
    self.input_dims = self._calc_input_dims(input_shape)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.input_dims, 64)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, output_shape[0])

    # Optimizer etc.
    self.device = T.device("cuda:0" if T.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=lr)
    self.loss = nn.MSELoss()
    self.to(self.device)

def _calc_input_dims(self, input_shape):
    """Calculate the input dimensions of the first fc layer"""
    x = T.zeros((1, 1) + input_shape)
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.maxpool1(x)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = self.maxpool2(x)
    x = self.conv3(x)
    x = self.maxpool3(x)

    return int(np.prod(x.size()))

def train_(
    self,
    train_data,   
    val_data=None,
    epochs=1,
    graph_path=None,
    progress=False,
):
    """Train the model on the provided data"""
    self.train()
    acc_hist = []
    loss_hist = []
    val_acc_hist = []
    val_loss_hist = []
    for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
        # Training loop                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        acc = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        loss = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        for X, y in train_data:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            l, a = self._training_step(X, y)
            loss += l                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            acc += a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        loss /= len(train_data)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        acc /= len(train_data)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        loss_hist.append(loss)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        acc_hist.append(acc)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        # Validation loop                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        v_acc = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        v_loss = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        if val_data:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            for X, y in val_data:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                l, a = self._validation_step(X, y)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                v_loss += l                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                v_acc += a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            v_loss /= len(val_data)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            v_acc /= len(val_data)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
            val_loss_hist.append(v_loss)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            val_acc_hist.append(v_acc)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        if progress:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            print(f"Epoch {epoch}: acc: {acc}, loss: {loss}")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            if val_data:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                print(f"\tval_acc: {v_acc}, val_loss: {v_loss}")
    if graph_path:
        mu.graph_training(
            {
                "acc": acc_hist,
                "loss": loss_hist,
                "val_acc": val_acc_hist,
                "val_loss": val_loss_hist,
            },
            graph_path,
        )
    
    return acc_hist, loss_hist

def _training_step(self, X, y):
    # TODO: This bit should be handled by data formatting
    # print(X[0][0], y)
    X = T.tensor([[X]], dtype=T.float, device=self.device)
    y = T.tensor([y], dtype=T.float, device=self.device)
    
    self.optimizer.zero_grad()
    y_ = self.forward(X)
    loss_ = self.loss(y_, y)
    loss_.backward()
    self.optimizer.step()
    
    loss = loss_.item()
    acc = int(list(y[0]).index(max(y[0])) == list(y_[0]).index(max(y_[0])))
    return loss, acc
    
def _validation_step(self, X, y):
    # TODO: This bit should be handled by data formatting
    X = T.tensor([[X]], dtype=T.float, device=self.device)
    y = T.tensor([y], dtype=T.float, device=self.device)
    
    y_ = self.forward(X)
    loss_ = self.loss(y_, y)
    
    loss = loss_.item()
    acc = int(list(y[0]).index(max(y[0])) == list(y_[0]).index(max(y_[0])))
    return loss, acc
    
def forward(self, x):
    # Make sure input is a tensor, and push it to gpu if possible
    if type(x) != T.Tensor:
        x = T.tensor(x, dtype=T.float, device=self.device)
    else:
        x.to(self.device)
    x = self.conv1(x)
    # x = F.relu(x)
    x = self.maxpool1(x)
    x = self.dropout(x)
    x = self.bn1(x)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = self.maxpool2(x)
    x = self.dropout(x)
    x = self.bn2(x)
    x = self.conv3(x)
    x = self.maxpool3(x)
    x = self.dropout(x)
    x = self.bn3(x)

    x = x.view(x.size()[0], -1)
    x = self.fc1(x)
    x = self.fc2(x)
    x = self.fc3(x)

    return x
```

Comment: do you normalize your inputs?

Comment: pretty difficult to guess without to see your code and the parameters you use. Could you share a bit more information about that?

Comment: Yes, input are normalized. I'm not sure what code to share, there's lots for processing data etc, but I'll add the code for the model.

Comment: You don't use any activation functions? This is essentially a linear model if not. I think you should also use a cross-entropy loss for your model. MSE isn't really optimal for classification tasks. Also, use the argmax function for your accuracy metric, it's a lot easier to interpret.

Comment: This is after fiddling with the model a bunch. Before. I was using cross-entropy loss and Relus. Thanks for the argmax tip though.